# How do I use the second parameter in the JavaScript 'prompt' function?

Tags: javascript

What is the second parameter used for in the prompt() function?

```
prompt('blahblahblah', 'WHY ARE THESE HERE? '){}
```

Comment: I really can't get what the question is but maybe I can answer : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.prompt

Comment: Do you mean the braces? Those do nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second param is for a `value` argument:

> value is a string containing the default value displayed in the text
>   input field. It is an optional parameter. Note that in Internet
>   Explorer 7 and 8, if you do not provide this parameter, the string
>   "undefined" is the default value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.prompt

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Exactly what I was looking for.  Never found the explanation in any of the books I've been reading, so hopefully this will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm going to assume that you wrote <s>parenthesis</s> parentheses  but *meant* parameter. I'm assuming this because you also mentioned the comma character and that only appears within the argument list of the command...

The second *parameter* in the prompt command is the default value that is inserted into the text field.

Here is a [simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/3HTJM/2/) -

```
var milliseconds = (new Date).getTime();
var currentEpoch = Math.floor(milliseconds / 1000);
prompt("What is the current epoch?",currentEpoch);
```

Answer (score 0):

`{}` defines an empty code block. It does exactly nothing.

It makes more sense to have a code block after control structures such as `if` and `for`.