# What is the second value in a prompt for?

Tags: javascript

I don't understand what the purpose of the second value in a prompt is for.

Ex:

```
var secretNumber = prompt("Pick a number between 1 and 5:","");
secretNumber = parseInt(secretNumber, 10);
```

I understand that the second value in the prompt is a placeholder value, but what's the point of a blank placeholder such as "" ?

Isn't it the same as just omitting the second value entirely if it's empty?

Thank You

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) is your friend.

Comment: I would assume that the blank `""` was provided to ensure that even if nothing was typed, it still returns a blank string, and not `undefined`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use the second parameter in the JavaScript 'prompt' function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118721/how-do-i-use-the-second-parameter-in-the-javascript-prompt-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second value is to have a default value in the prompt. According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt), The second parameter will be "undefined" for Explorer 7 and 8 by default.

The following code will return NaN (Not an Number) when secretNumber is undefined or an empty string.

```
secretNumber = parseInt(secretNumber, 10);
```

Comment: That makes more sense. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

The second value is the default value that will pre-populate the prompt's textbox. It's probably being set to nothing for compatibility with IE 7 and 8 as they would show "undefined" if nothing was provided.

Answer (score 0):

Default value. If the user just press enter this is will be the value

Answer (score 0):

It sets the default value for the prompt:

```
prompt('What is your name?', 'metalmoog');
```

---

[image: http://i.imgur.com/gfH70rY.png]